# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Substrate and Polkadot has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Dan Shields]

[image: Bruno]

[image: Shawn Tabrizi]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6173995352195072).

Comment: Thank you! Looking forward to build out the community further.

Comment: Looking forward to working with all of you!

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations and good luck with the community!

If you already reviewed all queues and flags, and also already closed all inappropriate questions, here are some things you should work on as new-elect moderators in your spare time for this new community (in random order):

- Find a creative name for the chat room.
- Fill the [on-topic help page](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) with instructions for new users to determine what's on topic for this community and whatnot.
- Do the same with the [tour page](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/tour). See also [this post](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88/160) for recommendations.
- Start adding tag wikis to the [most popular tags](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular); create sensible synonyms for tags that literally mean the same.
- Learn about [moderator-only tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work/47640#47640) such as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and use them wisely.
- Poke the Stack Exchange Staff for allowing [Community Ads](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/19/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/).
- [Vote early, vote often](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/).
- Show off with a golden [fanatic](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) badge ;)